# DropDownList is empty on postback if additional header row was added

Tags: .net, gridview, webforms, postback, dropdown

I have a GridView to which I add an additional header row during each postback.
For better understanding I show the code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddHeaderRow(); //everything fine if removed
}

private void AddHeaderRow()
{
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

    TableCell header = new TableHeaderCell();
    header.ColumnSpan = 1;
    row.Cells.Add(header);

    ((Table)grid.Controls[0]).Rows.AddAt(0, row);
}
```

I also have a DropDownList in the footer row of the grid which I use during validation.

```
protected void Validator_Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(source as Control).Parent.Parent;
    var drop = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("drop"); //with additional header row, contains no items!
}
```

When adding the header row, the DropDownList is found, but empty so that the validation crashes. If I remove that code it works. Is there a way to fix or avoid this problem?

Comment: Put your code inside !Page.IsPostBack

Comment: yes that would be possible, but I think I need to recreate the header during each postback, otherwise it is lost.

Comment: why not persist it in `ViewState`.